# [AWS} - Debug locally one or more lambda part of a step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'd like to understand if there's some way to debug one or more lambda(s) which are part of a step function.

I'm able to debug a single lambda with sam, Docker, AWS Toolkit together with Visual Studio Code and I see different tutorials to execute step functions locally. I'd like to understand if there's a way to debug a single lambda executing locally the relative step function.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your code not the lambda. Why is your code doing this, why does your code react like that.... Are you running tests?

You can create an event and execute that against your function running in the lambda.
You don't need to run any Sam or lambda locally. Just run tests against your function.